# Bigquery generate dynamic view

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to create a view to consolidating data that are in different tables.
For each year a new table appears ( I have no control over it) and the view has to fetch the data in this new table.
I can't modify/update these tables

the query view for one table (2022) :

```
with cte as (SELECT d.MULTIDIVISION_ZONE, s.ISO_COUNTRIES[OFFSET(0)] Country, d.DIVISION_CODE, BRAND, d.MULTIDIVISION_REGION,
    SUM(CASE
      WHEN PERIOD IN ('M01', 'M02', 'M03') THEN VALUE_AVERAGE_RATE
      ELSE 0
    END) YTD03,
    SUM(CASE
      WHEN PERIOD IN ('M01', 'M02', 'M03','M04', 'M05', 'M06') THEN VALUE_AVERAGE_RATE
      ELSE 0
    END) YTD06,
    SUM(CASE
      WHEN PERIOD IN ('M01', 'M02', 'M03','M04', 'M05', 'M06','M07', 'M08', 'M09') THEN VALUE_AVERAGE_RATE
      ELSE 0
    END) YTD09,
    SUM(CASE
      WHEN PERIOD IN ('M01', 'M02', 'M03','M04', 'M05', 'M06','M07', 'M08', 'M09','M010', 'M11', 'M12') THEN VALUE_AVERAGE_RATE
      ELSE 0
    END) YTD12
  FROM `dataset_source.table_name_prefix_2022_AGGREGATED` AS d
  JOIN `master_dataset.master_data_table` AS s
    ON s.MULTIDIVISION_CLUSTER_CODE= d.MULTIDIVISION_CLUSTER_CODE
  WHERE CODE = 'XXXXX'
  GROUP BY d.MULTIDIVISION_ZONE, Country, d.DIVISION_CODE, BRAND, d.MULTIDIVISION_REGION)


select MULTIDIVISION_ZONE as perimeter, sum(sales) as value, quarter from cte  
UNPIVOT(sales for quarter in (YTD03, YTD06, YTD09, YTD12))
GROUP BY MULTIDIVISION_ZONE, quarter
UNION ALL
select brand, sum(sales), quarter from cte  
UNPIVOT(sales for quarter in (YTD03, YTD06, YTD09, YTD12))
GROUP BY brand, quarter
UNION ALL
select MULTIDIVISION_REGION, sum(sales), quarter from cte  
UNPIVOT(sales for quarter in (YTD03, YTD06, YTD09, YTD12))
GROUP BY MULTIDIVISION_REGION, quarter
```

my goal is to create a view from this query but dynamic.

the From clause: `dataset_source.table_name_prefix_2022_AGGREGATED` so for 2023, 2024,2025 ... so on but does not exist yet (`dataset_source.table_name_prefix_2023_AGGREGATED` does not exist yet) and I can't use * (wildcard) because there are views on the same dataset and this is bigquery limitation
From documentation

> The wildcard table functionality does not support views. If the wildcard table matches any view in the dataset, the query returns an error. This is true whether or not your query contains a WHERE clause on the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column to filter out the view.

What is the best option(s) in order to achieve that?
Thank you

Comment: Do you want to generate the views once? and to have 1 view per year?

Comment: views once should be better, but if not possible multiple view per year. The issue with the last, is that i dont know when the new table will be created

Comment: Hi @RaphaelObadia, for your requirement, you can use [table functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions#creating_a_table_function) which are similar to views. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar It can be a good idea. But two questions. In the table function it will be necessary to be able to make a loop on the current year and all that has before eg. Year N = 2024, and loop on 2023, 2022, 2021 and union all everything. The second question is, if possible to create a view from a query that calls a table function

Comment: Hi @RaphaelObadia, For both the questions, I would suggest you use [Python client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries). You can create a loop inside which you can loop on the  year. And for your second question also you can try creating a view using python client library to call table function. Let me  know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use [table functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions#creating_a_table_function) or table valued functions that return a table and are similar to views. It is different from views in a way that it can take parameters. You can call a table function for any valid table. For every year, you can try to loop over the years using the [Python Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) or you can pass the year as a parameter. For second use case of creating a view, you can try that using the python client library and try to call the table functions from that view.